# Error in source bashrc for activating virtual env

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I want to activate my python virtual_env created by conda. So, I need these three commands:

```
source ~/.bashrc
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
source activate my_env
```

but with source ~/.bashrc I get the following errors:

```
bash: groups: command not found
bash: awk: command not found
bash: whoami: command not found
```

what is the solution?

Comment: Ignoring whatever problem is causing those errors, why do you need to source `.bashrc` in the first place? It was already sourced when you started your interactive shell, and if there's something in there you need for a *noninteractive* shell, then you should move that somewhere else.

Comment: Possibly related https://askubuntu.com/a/186817